# CDK diff with read-only permissions - what is a good way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

New version of CDK deployment strategy allows a user assume roles like cdk-{qualifier}-deploy.

I want to give a developer an ability to perform cdk diff from their local machine, but behind the scenes cdk diff assumes cdk-{qualifier}-deploy role, which is the power I'm saving for CICD pipeline with a secret IAM user and trust to deploy.

I removed the deploy ability from the local IAM user and ran some CDK Diff. The stack does quite a bit with lambda, ecs, r53, and vpcs.

Here's the policy i was able to give local user to make this work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CDKDiff",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123:stack/OnDemandStackUE1/*",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:sa-east-1:123:stack/OnDemandStackSE1/*",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-2:123:stack/OnDemandStackEU2/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i get output for a small change:

```
Assuming role failed: User: arn:aws:iam::123:user/dummy is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::123:role/cdk-me-deploy-role
current credentials could not be used to assume '...deploy-role..', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
Resources
[~] AWS::Lambda::Function ecsd_lambda ecslambda3D927DBA
 └─ [~] Timeout
     ├─ [-] 10
     └─ [+] 9
```

Looks like it works with a most minimal user permissions to DescribeStacks and GetTemplate. Is this an adequate solution? Should i try to have a role instead via synthesizer stack or something?

Comment: Those are almost certainly not enough permissions. Are you sure your current user does not have much more permissions?

Comment: Yes. I did:: cdk diff -e OnDemandStackUE1 -v --debug --profile dummy :: and it worked with a single inline policy listed above

Comment: I submitted a bug report for this https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17150